# Dedekind-Infinite Set s.t. $|A\times A|=|A|$

Tags: set-theory

I know that a set $A$ is Dedekind-infinite iff $|A|+1=|A|$.

Is it possible to prove $|A|\times n=|A|$? (in ZF)

More specifically: $|A\times A|=|A|$ where A is Dedekind-infinite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. It is consistent that there is a set that is Dedekind-infinite, and every subset is countable or co-countable. It is easy to see that neither equalities hold for such a set.

Answer (score 2):

If X is a Dedekind-finite infinite set, then $X\sqcup \mathbb {N} $ is a counterexample.